EF Core navigation by GUID
I have two entities:
Parent entity:
public class Personnel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; } 
    public Base64Record.Base64Record? SignatureRecord { get; set; }
}

Child entity:
public class Base64Record
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public Guid Guid { get; set; }
    public Guid ParentGuid { get; set; }
}

Id is the primary key in both entities but I would like to connect them by the Guid
Something like this
modelBuilder.Entity<Personnel.Personnel>()
            .HasOne(x => x.SignatureData)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.Guid);

This however throws an error

Unable to create a 'DbContext' of type ''. The exception 'The specified type 'System.String' must be a non-interface reference type to be used as an entity type.' was thrown while attempting to create an instance.

Is what I am looking for possible without making Guid primary key on both entities?

Add WithPrincipalKey(p => p.Guid) This tells EF to link to the Guid column instead of the PK. (Id)  Note that Guids are not ideal for indexing. Having a numeric FK linked to the clustered index PK is generally a much better option for performance.
